# upload files via iPad

Tags: ipad, safari

One of our users just notified us that our web application works very well through Safari on the iPad (or whatever the default browser is -- I assume Safari).  The only thing that doesn't work is the file upload part.

Our web application enables our users to attach files in various parts of the system.

I was thinking about this.  The iPhone takes pictures, but doesn't really give me the ability to upload them via a standard web interface (where you click a button, choose a file, upload the file, etc).

Is this even possible?  Or is the only way to upload files from an iPhone/iPad via a custom app written for the device?

Is there a way to upload a file on an iPad via the web browser?

Comment: Wish iPhone/iPad had this capability...I can upload images from my Android to my web app using the file upload control with no issues...and the file system is fairly protected...feels pretty secure to me!

Comment: Does iOS8 add support for other types other then images?

Comment: It's 2016. Is Apple still back in 1984 with Orwell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know the iOS doesn't expose a file system to the user, so it wouldn't really make sense for it to be possible to upload files via a web interface. Most of the apps that do exist, sync files through iTunes or something similar.

One approach I've also seen used was for the iOS device to act as a fileserver and enabling you to download files that way. This is how iFile works.

In short, to my knowledge it isn't possible.

Comment: iOS6 supports file uploads for images - see here: http://ipadinsight.com/ios-6/ios-6-and-ipad-image-uploads-working-nicely/

Answer (score 11):

This ability was shown during the 2012 WWDC keynote.  I believe details are under NDA unless you're a registered iOS developer.  Take a look at the iOS 6 beta documentation.

This post has a photo of the keynote slide highlighting "photo upload" as a new feature.
http://www.anandtech.com/show/5987/ios-6-safari

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mobile safari on iPhone/iPad does not allow file uploads (the file upload button/widget is displayed disabled), however you can re-enable that feature by calling a third-party uploader app from your web app/site.

Have a look at http://www.aurigma.com/iphone/ for such an uploader app.

Answer (score 2):

There are some replacement web browsers you can get from the app store that allow you to upload.  You use them instead of Safari.  One example is iCab Mobile.

Comment: interestingly Google Chrome on iOS doesn't support uploads

Comment: Highly unlikely that other browsers on iOS support something that Safari doesn't as every single browser on iOS is basically Safari with that vendor's UI on top of it. Apple doesn't allow browsers to ship their own engine.

Answer (score 1):

There is now way via HTML5 on iOS6+ devices.

`<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">`

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775971/1783439

I've tested it in Safari on an ipad with iOS9.