# Camera access through browser

Tags: ios, html, camera

We are creating an HTML5 website for mobile and need to get camera access through the web browser without being a native app. We are having trouble making this work in iOS. Is anyone aware of a solution for this?

Answer (score 129):

You could try this:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">
```

but it **has to be iOS 6+** to work. That will give you a nice dialogue for you to choose either to take a picture or to upload one from your album i.e.

[image: Screenhot]

An example can be found here:
[Capturing camera/picture data without PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap)

Comment: This is AWESOME on Android too!

Comment: Nice demo for uploading to a server. Anyone know how to modify this to save the picture to a local album on the device?

Comment: The only problem is that, at least on iphone (ios 7.0.4) at least at the moment it creates a temporary image named always `'image.jpg'`. So if you upload a few images in the same form, they overwrite each other due to same name unless you do something to rename them, be careful!

Comment: @K.Niemczyk: did you ever figure that out? if so i'd be interested in the solution. I found this: http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/ (see examples 6-7 for local storage)

Comment: @Leon Not directly. We ended up switching to using Phonegap for our needs for several other reasons.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution on iPad. Could you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21885144/902025) and tell me where it can come from? Thanks

Comment: Apologies for down-vote.  Miss-clicked and then couldn't correct after an hour+ later.

Comment: This is great, however does anyone know why if u choose existing pic its around 150kb in size, however if u take photo they always seem to be like 1.50mb. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Brilliant.  [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/6y2rdk1p/) for anyone wanting to give this code a test run on their device.

Comment: Just be aware that on iOS it gives you the *choice* of taking a photo or choosing an existing photo.  On Android is immediately launches the camera without asking.

Comment: @SimonEast: There are [five fiddles in this question about the `input` element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong) with `accept="image/*"`.

Answer (score 34):

As of 2015, it now ***just works***.

```
<input type="file">
```

This will ask user for the upload of any file.  On iOS 8.x this can be a camera video, camera photo, or a photo/video from Photo Library.

[image: iOS/iPhone photo/video/file upload]

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

This is as above, but limits the uploads to *photos* only from camera or library, no videos.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict users from choosing a file from the photo library? I want to accept only a newly taken image.

Comment: @Daryl not on iOS. Android supports the `capture` attribute which does just that. See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Comment: shall I close this Take Photo or Video and Photo Library popup after some time in user not click on it.

Comment: looks like the video functions is not there anymore?

Answer (score 26):

In iOS6, Apple supports this via the `<input type="file">` tag.  I couldn't find a useful link in Apple's developer documentation, but there's an example [here](https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/).

It looks like overlays and more advanced functionality is not yet available, but this should work for a lot of use cases.

EDIT: [The w3c has a spec that iOS6 Safari seems to implement a subset of.](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/) The `capture` attribute is notably missing.

Answer (score 10):

I think this one is working.
Recording a video or audio;

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

or (new method)

```
<device type="media" onchange="update(this.data)"></device>
<video autoplay></video>
<script>
  function update(stream) {
    document.querySelector('video').src = stream.url;
  }
</script>
```

If it is not, probably will work on ios6, more detail can be found at [get user media](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Answer (score 5):

**Update 11/2020**: The Google Developer link is (currently) dead. The original article with a LOT more explanations can still be found at [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201004045109/https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/).

---

This question is already a few years old but in that time some additional possibilities have evolved, like accessing the camera directly, displaying a preview and capturing snapshots (e.g. for QR code scanning).

This [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/) article provides an in-depth explaination of all (?) the ways how to get image/camera data into a web application, from "work everywhere" (even in desktop browsers) to "work only on modern, up-to-date mobile devices with camera". Along with many useful tips.

Explained methods:

- Ask for a URL: Easiest but least satisfying.
- File input (covered by most other posts here): The data can then be attached to a  or manipulated with JavaScript by listening for an onchange event on the input element and then reading the files property of the event target.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-input">
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => doSomethingWithFiles(e.target.files));
</script>
```

The `files` property is a FileList object.

- Drag and drop (useful for desktop browsers):

```
<div id="target">You can drag an image file here</div>
<script>
  const target = document.getElementById('target');

  target.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    doSomethingWithFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  });

  target.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
  });
</script>
```

You can get a `FileList` object from the `dataTransfer.files` property of the `drop` event.

- Paste from clipboard

```
<textarea id="target">Paste an image here</textarea>
<script>
  const target = document.getElementById('target');

  target.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomethingWithFiles(e.clipboardData.files);
  });
</script>
```

`e.clipboardData.files` is a `FileList` object again.

- Access the camera interactively (necessary if application needs to give instant feedback on what it "sees", like QR codes): Detect camera support with `const supported = 'mediaDevices' in navigator;` and prompt the user for consent. Then show a realtime preview and copy snapshots to a canvas.

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
<script>
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

  const constraints = {
    video: true,
  };

  captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });

  // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to stop the video stream with

```
player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```

**Update 11/2020**: The Google Developer link is (currently) dead. The original article with a LOT more explanations can still be found at [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201004045109/https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/).

Comment: This is why link answers should also include the specifics in the answer, links break.

Comment: I dug up the original article in a web archive and added examples. Would appreciate the undoing of the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

The [Picup](http://picupapp.com/) app is a way to take pictures from an HTML5 page and upload them to your server. It requires some extra programming on the server, but apart from PhoneGap, I have not found another way.

Comment: In iOS8 you don't need Picup anymore. HTML5 supports <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera">. Verified in Safari and Chrome.