# Web Cam integration in mvc3

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

please help me for web cam integration in mvc 3.0 in asp.net with code.
This is my **C#** code body.

```
public ActionResult UploadWebCamPic(string ImageData)
{
    byte[] upImg = null;
    WebImage wi = new WebImage(Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData));
    upImg = wi.GetBytes("png");
    //Get a data Context and you now have the image in PNG format
    //in the upImg byte[] that you can store in your DB.
    return Json("OK");
}
```

And here is my **JavaScript** Code.
[Javascript Code](http://pastie.org/4685628)

namespace webimage not found error is coming

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks !!

Comment: Any errors or something more to add?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery webcam plugin with asp.net mvc 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447992/jquery-webcam-plugin-with-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is making a reference to a class called `WebImage` but you either haven't imported the namespace for that class or you're missing an assembly reference.