# Opening iOS camera using HTML5 without Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html

I am using html5 code and trying to open camera using `<input type="file">`. It's working fine on Android but not on iOS.

How can I access camera from iOS platform using HTML5 (without Phonegap)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Camera Access Through Browser in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput">
```

but it **has to be iOS 6+** to work.

An example can be found here:

[Capturing camera/picture data without PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 1):

iOS currently doesn't support this functionality sorry. Alternatives some web apps are using are things like emailing in with files attached (Basecamp does this) and there is also an app that enables them called [Picup](http://picupapp.com/) which you can suggest users user your app with to use the file upload fields.

Comment: It's not your fault. Don't be sorry. Although hopefully iPhone supports the video tag and `getUserMedia()` in the future.

Comment: HTML5 video should work, but yeah, getUserMedia() you'll have to wait for :)