# Is it possible to take a photo with an iPad from a web page?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, camera, photo

I'm building a web intranet app that will track inventory and I would like to be able to take a photo of each item using the built in camera from an iPad. Is this possible?

I've done a similar thing with barcodes using an app, but I haven't found anything that will do the same with a photo yet.

Answer (score 3):

This stack overflow question may help:

[HTML5 Camera Access Through Browser in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios)

@user295691 writes:

> In IOS6 apple supports this via the < input type=file > tag. I
>   couldn't find a useful link in Apple's developer documentation, but
>   there's an example here
>   http://www.aaronlumsden.com/articles/ios6-the-benefits-for-html5-web-app-development/

Answer (score 1):

You can use PhoneGap framework to achieve this. JavaScript is used as bridge between Web app and Native functionality.