# Making an iOS file input go directly to the camera app?

Tags: ios, file-upload, safari, camera, mobile-safari

Background: iOS 6.1, at the time of writing, doesn't allow both multiple file selection and taking a photo in a single input.

Since my main app already has a multiple input picker for choosing files, I'd like to add a second button (only required by, and only shown on) iOS devices to start the camera.

This currently works with:

```
<input type="file" class="ios_only" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

However iOS Safari always gives the following dialog:

[image: iOS 'take photo' or 'choose exiting' dialog]

Is there a way the `<input>` can be made to go directly to the camera without this prompt?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't. Safari handles this as an `UIImagePickerView` and has to choose the source by this `UIActionSheet`.

For your information, this line has the same effect:

```
<input type="file" class="ios_only" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Tested also in iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

For multiple file uploads:

```
<input capture="camera" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="" />
```