# jQuery-File-Upload does not offer to take a picture on an i-pad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-file-upload

the issue is this,
When you use the HTML file input type , all/most mobile browsers offer you the choice to 
Take a picture or Select from a gallery

On the i-Pad this is shown as 
•   Take Photo Or  video
•   Photo Library

If you click on Photo Library it gives you an option to
•   Load from the gallery.

When using the **jQuery-File-Upload** (that offers multiple files uploads and drag & drop etc)  , on the I-pad it **skips** the first step and goes straight to Load from Gallery .  This is a major problem for us  .

Using the official demo of the libraries we use https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ this behaves in the same way, so I have to assume our implementation is correct

Note: 
•   This also does not work when using Chrome on an i-Phone 
•   This does seem to work as expected on Android devices

Any ideas gratefully received ..

Comment: Don't know if it solves your problem, but did you try to add capture=camera to the input type file, sounds helpful for me: http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that, but no luck. I did find out its the restriction in IOS when using multiple file type

Answer (score 2):

Some more research , tells me its the multiple file type attribute that restricts this. IOS does not let you use camera as source when using the multiple file selector .

Issue confirmed  here [Making an iOS file input go directly to the camera app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688415/making-an-ios-file-input-go-directly-to-the-camera-app)

and more info on this page http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers