# Take a picture button in html 5

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, android-camera

How is it possible to make a "take a picture" button using html 5 ?
I know that by adding an

```
<input type="file" />
```

Android devices will ask the user to choose a source ...
One of the sources is the camera.

however in iphone devices it will open the gallery to choose a picture the user wants to upload.

is it possible to create a button that will open the camera on both devices? (what about windows phones ?)

I am looking for a solution that can utilize any html-mobile framework i.e. phonegap, cordova etc...

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. But this format looks good for taking picture form.

html

```
<h4>Take a Picture</h4>
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
       <input type="file" id="file2"  name="file2" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
       <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="sendFile();" />
</form>
```

[IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios)

[image]

Comment: This work in Androd 7,8 but new Android 9 don't works.