# how m.facebook.com is able to run native mobile actions like camera and gallery ?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, native

when I visit https://m.facebook.com/ I can  upload a picture from gallery , or take picture from camera.

How it is possible that a website is able to run native actions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios basically, the iOS developers allow certain form types to perform certain actions. Same for other developers. Just search.

Comment: This is a solution for iOS only, but for facebook it works on android too

Comment: Apache Cordova can access your device using javascript. I'm just not sure if you can use it on a website

Comment: Like I said, it works the same with other devices. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Hey folks, this question is not a duplicate of the iOS question.  The answers may be the same, but the questions are different.

Comment: as @brad Said it's not the same question I havent specified any platform here , m.facebook.com works on android, ios , wp ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

Compatability:

- Android 3.0 browser - one of the first implementations. Check out this video to see it in action.
- Chrome for Android (0.16)
- Firefox Mobile 10.0
- iOS6 Safari and Chrome (partial support)

[source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: This is the best method, as if the device doesn't support capture, it still functions as a file upload.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tryed something like this?

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/