# Scanning QR or barcodes on iPhone or Android in with just HTML 5

Tags: android, iphone, html, qr-code

I was wondering if there is a way to develop a cross-platform HTML 5 app that can scan QR and or bar codes with the phone's camera.  Some of the answers I have seen are a few years old now and so I am hoping this technology has improved.  None of the demos that were mentioned, such as http://webqr.com  http://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode http://www.themedone.com/qr-scanner-generator/scan.html worked on my iPhone 4.  Thank you.

Comment: image capture - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31935989/372215

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather old, there appeared a number of technologies that may be used to scan QR/bar codes in the browser efficiently. For example, WASM or [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/). Here are a couple of nice articles on this technology:

- [WebAssembly at Ebay](https://tech.ebayinc.com/engineering/webassembly-at-ebay-a-real-world-use-case/)
- [Barcode Scanner WebAssembly](https://barkeywolf.consulting/posts/barcode-scanner-webassembly/)

To summarise, one could make use of the [zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar) C/C++ library and transpile it to WebAssembly (which is supported by all major browsers) using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/).

Here is my attempt to solve this (works well on iOS and Android):

- https://github.com/maslick/koder
- https://qr.maslick.tech

Another approach would be to use some kind of JavaScript library, e.g. [jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR). This solution is not as performant compared to WASM, so you can try to offload your Browser's Main thread by using a [Web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score -2):

The hard part of this question looks like it has a solution here:

[Capturing camera/picture data without PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap)

I was able to connect to a html page on my web server with this code and take photos with both Safari and Chrome on my iPhone 4.

Comment: your capturing picture link is broken