# Take photo from website using devices camera?

Tags: ios, html

I know i can use this to allow the user to use the devices camera:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

On iOS this comes up with a bubble asking the user to take photo or choose existing.

Is there a way to force this to just launch the devices camera rather than allowing the user to choose existing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios

Comment: thanks, that links contains the same info as my question, but not the answer.

Comment: Have you tried getUserMedia?

Comment: You cannot "force" this with html. It's privacy and you need permission to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```