# How can I use a mobile friendly rear-facing camera

Tags: node.js, html, mobile, camera

I'm building an application with the MEAN stack that allows users to use a mobile device's rear-facing camera through a browser. I am looking for a way to utilize a rear-facing camera to take a photo and save it to a database where I'll use it in a inventory system. I have looked at HTML5's getUserMedia() but seems to use mostly Audio and Video. Can anyone point me in a direction that will be useable across up-to-date browsers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate answer : [HTML5 Camera Access Through Browser in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336641/html5-camera-access-through-browser-in-ios)

You would use 
    `<input type="file" id="take-picture" accept="image/*">` to prompt the user for access to their camera.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/API/Camera_API/Introduction

Works on Android 3.0+ and iOS 6.0+