# File upload using javascript (iPad web application)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upload files via iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081997/upload-files-via-ipad)

Hey guy's I'm trying to create a "native" iPad application using html, javascript, and html5 cache manifest so it will be available off line.  I have it working with jquery and using jspdf to export the pdf.  I would like to be able for the user to load data from a csv file upload.  There seems to be a way to parse csv's with javascript but is it possible to do a file upload using nothing but javascript(and the user is offline).  In my mind this won't work(need server interaction) but I'm not 100% sure.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to access the file system from safari in the current versions of iOS

[upload files via iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081997/upload-files-via-ipad)