# Previewing and Uploading images on smartphones

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to write a script that will allow a user to upload a picture taken by (or selected from) their phone when on my jquerymobile driven site.
I've found that AJAX doesn't allow file submissions in a form and I will have to use the following line

```
<form method=”POST” enctype=”multipart/form-data” action=”process_update.php” data-ajax=”false”>
```

for the form itself, but I can't find anyway to tell the smartphone to prompt the user to choose between selecting a photograph on their phone or taking a new one.

How do I accomplish this?  Would I be better off looking into using some sort of plugin?

I plan on performing cropping and size changes on the server side as part of the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Samsung Galaxy S II device's browser (webkit = 534.30) and the following form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process_update.php">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*; capture=camera" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The device prompts me to choose camera or gallery when pressing the file input button.  I believe it's the accept="image/*..." attribute that's triggering this behavior in webkit.

Comment: Do you know if thats a universal command, or does that just effect android phones?

Comment: iOS webkit blocks file upload with inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4082032/1367983

Confirmed as much with ipad just now.

Comment: Interesting thing; if I'm reading that correctly, iOS6 is the first version to allow it seems.